# Replicating @ElementCollection behavior

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is there anyway I can have the effect of @ElementCollection without actually having this annotation? I am using Hibernate 3.3, while @ElementCollection and @CollectionTable is only supported for Hibernate 3.5 and beyond. But I really need to use these annotations, for a case like this:

http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/elementcollection_hibernate_annotation
(Where we get the List of Strings rather than List of the full entity)

Comment: you mean put it in "orm.xml" instead of annotations?

Comment: No still use annotations but without those 2 particular annotations

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<element>` tag to do the same operation, refer to this link from hibernate documentation:

[7.2.3. Collections of basic types and embeddable objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-ofvalues)

The example given in the link is :

```
<element
        column="column_name"                               (1)
        formula="any SQL expression"                       (2)
        type="typename"                                    (3)
        length="L"
        precision="P"
        scale="S"
        not-null="true|false"
        unique="true|false"
        node="element-name"
/>

1   column (optional): the name of the column holding the collection element values.
2   formula (optional): an SQL formula used to evaluate the element.
3   type (required): the type of the collection element.
```

Refer to this link for an example: 
[Collection Mapping](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/java/hibernate_mapping_examples)

**Star.java**

```
private Set<String> planets = new HashSet<String>();
```

**Star.hbm.xml**

```
<set name="planets" table="star_planet">
    <key column="star_id" />
    <element type="text"/>
</set>
```

**Update:**

You have to use either xml mapping or annotations for a given entity class but not both at a time.

If you want to see examples only using annotations then there are so many available if you search in Google, please check and let me know if you have issues in implementing them.

Finally, yes it works with Set of Strings, integers or Long etc.

**Update:**

Here is a simple example that shows how to use element collections:

**User.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "Addresses", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "street1", column = @Column(name = "fld_street")) })
    public Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, Address... addresses){
        this.name = name;
        this.addresses.addAll(Arrays.asList(addresses));
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }   
}
```

**Address.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String street1;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
    }

    public String getStreet1() {
        return street1;
    }

    public void setStreet1(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return street1;
    }
}
```

Simple logic to test this:

```
private static void showUsers() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User").list();

    for (User user : users) {
        System.out.println(user.getName() + " -- > " + user.getAddresses());
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
}

private static void saveUsers() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    User user1 = new User("U1", new Address("A1"), new Address("A11"));
    User user2 = new User("U2", new Address("A2"));
    session.save(user1);
    session.save(user2);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: Can this all be done using annotations? The entity class I'm using is written only with annotations. I'm not even sure if its possible to mix annotations and .xml, but can you show how to replicate this using annotations? Would be VERY helpful!

Comment: Also I assume this will work whether its Set<String> or Set<Integer> or Set<Long> etc.

Comment: I have been trying to solve this problem for weeks using annotations and have not come up with a working solution. Just to be clear (I think you understand), but I need a collection of a column from a different table. Any helpful/link or solution for this using annotations and I will be grateful FOR LIFE! I don't think Googling will help though I have tried.

Comment: I need to do what you did with annotations (But get Set of Strings) WITHOUT using ElementCollection. My 1st sentence in my question was " Is there anyway I can have the effect of ElementCollection without actually having this annotation?" I suppose it is not possible to have the affect of ElementCollection for my use case through other annotations

Comment: Since using any other annotation will not work, lets go back to your .xml solution. In my case Star.java is written all in annotations. I don't want to change the whole class but I also know we can't mix annotations with xml mapping for a given entity. Is there any way around this for me? I still just want the set of strings in Star

Comment: I appreciate your efforts @Chaitanya

Comment: @james, no you can use either annotations or xml mapping but you cannot mix them at the same time for a given entity. Also as per official document there is only single annotation - `@ElementCollection` if you need a collection of elements to use with hibernate, so I guess there is no alternate annotation available.

Comment: Do you think its possible to work around this? In Star.java (the class full of annotations) have a wrapper class around the List of Strings, and create a .xml file for this simple wrapper class with the .xml content you described. Do you get where I am going with this? Do you think its possible?

Comment: @James, I am not sure if it works like that but you can try it.

Comment: One last question that just occurred to me reading you XML mapping solution. star_id is the String column I am getting back from the star_planet table fine. But where is the join key specified? For example, in your CollectionTable the join column is "user_id". I mean in general, we are getting back a list of a column, but what column determines this OneToMany relationnship and where is that specified?

Comment: Does that make sense? I mean for your example, suppose we have a Star entity that has a list of Planets and we just want the planet names back. We have to specify the column we want back from Planets (planet_name) AND the pk fk relationship between Stars and Planets (star_id). We can't just get away by specifying just one of them.